# Monitor for Wifi Connected and Disconnected States via Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, wifi, state, broadcast, monitor

I'm developing an app, where I need a broadcast receiver which will monitor for wifi connected and disconnected states.
I've tried many codes, browsed lots of stackoverflow posts, but no success.
I haven't found any such method/code which work properly, some codes are not working at all, some are returning wrong info, some are making broadcast receiver crash/restart and much more.
So, is there any full proof method to monitor for wifi connected/disconnected states which works for all versions of android starting from 4.0.3 Icecream sandwitch?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to define a broadcast receiver which can listen for network change event.

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String TYPE_NET_CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (TYPE_NET_CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            boolean connected = NetworkStatus.isNetworkConnected(context);
            if (connected) {
                //Connected

            } else {
              //Disconnected
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now register your receiver in manifest like:-

```
<application
       ...>
    <receiver android:name=". NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: have you checked? is it really working? I can't check as I'm out of my home today, can you please confirm the same? also, why phonestate permission? also, in onReceive, we are not listening for android.net.wifi.WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION then how will it respond for wifi connection/disconnection?

Comment: I am same using in my existing application and it is working. I assume you have provided Internet permissions because without it you won't listen to any event.

Comment: Hi AVI, actually, I need to only detect that wifi is connected or disconnected, then why internet and phone permission?

Comment: You can remove phone_state if data connection not required.